# (Firebase and NodeMCU) How to reduce the delay time when control led?

Tags: led, nodemcu

My project consists of NodeMCU controlling led from Firebase's RealTime Database (Using Esp8266Firebase library)
The problem is that the delayed time is too long ( about 6 seconds from when I change the value on the server until the led is turn ON or OFF)

My code on NodeMCU 1.0

```cpp
#include "FirebaseESP8266.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "-6c5d7.firebaseio.com"   
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "hYIBAaJYb8nGPuo8Q9EfZuAIfV"   

//define ledPin
int ledPin = 2; //D4

void setup(){
    //setup pinLed
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);


    //setup general
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    WifiConnect();
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void getConfirmDataForLed() {

    int controlValue;
    Firebase.getInt(firebaseData,"/Control/ControlValue",controlValue);

    switch(controlValue) {

        case 1: 
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            break;
        default:
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            break;
    }


}

void WifiConnect(){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
    }

    Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());

    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
    Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
    //Set database read timeout to 1 minute (max 15 minutes)
    Firebase.setReadTimeout(firebaseData, 1000 * 60);
    //tiny, small, medium, large and unlimited.
    //Size and its write timeout e.g. tiny (1s), small (10s), medium (30s) and large (60s).
    Firebase.setwriteSizeLimit(firebaseData, "tiny");
    delay(1000);
}

void loop(){
    getConfirmDataForLed();
    delay(500);
}
```

Firebase's Structure

```
Control
    |
    |--ControlValue : 0
```

Comment: what is the average response time of firebase in your area?

Comment: When I use my android phone to send data to firebase, It changes very quickly, but it only slows on the Node

Comment: @Thang Do not reveal your Firebase auth details publicly like this. It may be misused.